# In C++, unable to dereference vector iterator **caused by memset() to vector**

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

I have a vector of pointers-to-structs.

```
std::vector<REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK*> rl_block;
```

The struct is defined in a header...

```
struct REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK
{
    int                    number_of_entries;
    REVOCATION_LIST_ENTRY *entries;
    SIGDATA                signature;
};
```

Later, the vector has one entry added, like this:

```
REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK *new_rl_block = new REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK;
new_rl_block->number_of_entries = 6;
rl_block.push_back(new_rl_block);
```

Later, I want to access the data within rl_block:

```
std::vector<REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK*>::iterator it;
it = rl_block.begin();
number = (*it)->number_of_entries;
```

But this gets me the 'ol assertion:

```
vector iterator not dereferencable
```

Note, however, that I *am* able to do this, and get the value '6' back, as expected:

```
REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK *block = rl_block[0];
number = block->number_of_entries_in_this_signature_block;
```

What am I missing with the iterator way?

***EDIT***

Thanks folks for your comments.  The `rl_block` is part of another struct (this code uses a complicated set of nested structs).  If I write a bit of test code that does not have the rl_block inside of another struct, everything works as expected.

As a result, I modified the rl_block definition to:

```
std::vector<REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK*> *rl_block;
```

and then allocate the vector itself dynamically.  This works.  But why?

Digging further, I found the issue --- a lousy `memset()` of the containing structure to zero-out the memory.  This works for P.O.D., but not for the vectors, of course.

Comment: Btw what compiler do you use?

Comment: With the current project,  it's MS Visual Studio 2012.  This is a runtime assertion though.

Comment: Please present a **complete** and **compileable** example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Side remark: A Standard Library container storing raw owning pointers is often error prone, you might want to consider using `unique_ptr` to manage the lifetime (`vector< unique_ptr<REVOCATION_LIST_BLOCK> >`).

Comment: You're messing up your memory somewhere. Present your debugging testcase.

Comment: Thanks for the comments -- please see my edit to the original question.

Comment: @dyp Can you specify why an STL container owning pointers is more error prone than normal pointer logic?  Obviously, I will have to deallocate any internally-allocated memory -- anything else?  Thanks for the tip regarding unique_ptr.

Comment: @Eric You can easily remove and overwrite elements of an StdLib container such as `vector<some_type*>`. Doing so *without* explicitly freeing/deleting the removed pointers will cause leaks. It's not necessarily more error prone than "normal pointer logic" (I interpret that as `some_type** cont = new some_type*[10]; cont[0] = new some_type(42);`), but most probably more error prone than `vector<unique_ptr<int>>`.

Comment: why `memset` exists in C++ code...